# Google Maps Markers inconsistent as they're drawn?

Tags: google-maps

I've playing around with the google maps api and am puzzled at the following behavior.  If I use `mPoint` as the LatLng for my marker, the marker is rendered on a different point on the map as opposed to putting the same value directly into the properties of the marker.  Code chunk is as follows:

```
        var mPoint = [new google.maps.LatLng(38.991300,-76.936165)];
//        var GPoint = new google.maps.Marker({map:map,position:AVPoint});
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.991300,-76.936165),
    //position: new google.maps.LatLng(mPoint),
    draggable: true
  });
```

Why would this happen?

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
var mPoint = [new google.maps.LatLng(38.991300,-76.936165)];
```

You define an array as mPoint. And it absolutely makes no sense to pass this array to the marker object that you are creating since the position attribute expects a latlng object and not an array as argument.

In your case `var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: mPoint[0], draggable: true});` would be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps Marker Example (with drop/drag animation)
reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/

```
<script>
  var mPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(38.991300,-76.936165);
  var marker;
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: mPoint
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map:map,
      draggable:true,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      position: mPoint
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);
  }

  function toggleBounce() {

    if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
      marker.setAnimation(null);
    } else {
      marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Source:
https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations